# Confusion About Implementing LeafSystem With Vector Output Port Correctly

Tags: python-3.x, drake, control-theory

I'm a student teaching myself Drake, specifically pydrake with Dr. Russ Tedrake's excellent Underactuated Robotics course. I am trying to write a combined energy shaping and lqr controller for keeping a cartpole system balanced upright. I based the diagram on the cartpole example found in Chapter 3 of Underactuated Robotics [http://underactuated.mit.edu/acrobot.html], and the SwingUpAndBalanceController on Chapter 2: [http://underactuated.mit.edu/pend.html].

I have found that due to my use of the `cart_pole.sdf model` I have to create an abstract input port due receive `FramePoseVector` from the `cart_pole.get_output_port(0)`. From there I know that I have to create a control signal output of type BasicVector to feed into a Saturation block before feeding into the cartpole's actuation port.

The problem I'm encountering right now is that I'm not sure how to get the system's current state data in the `DeclareVectorOutputPort`'s callback function. I was under the assumption I would use the `LeafContext` parameter in the callback function, `OutputControlSignal`, obtaining the `BasicVector` continuous state vector. However, this resulting vector, `x_bar` is always `NaN`. Out of desperation (and testing to make sure the rest of my program worked) I set `x_bar` to the controller's initialization `cart_pole_context` and have found that the simulation runs with a control signal of 0.0 (as expected). I can also set `output` to 100 and the cartpole simulation just flies off into endless space (as expected).

TL;DR: What is the proper way to obtain the continuous state vector in a custom controller extending `LeafSystem` with a `DeclareVectorOutputPort`?

Thank you for any help! I really appreciate it :) I've been teaching myself so it's been a little arduous haha.

```
# Combined Energy Shaping (SwingUp) and LQR (Balance) Controller
# with a simple state machine
class SwingUpAndBalanceController(LeafSystem):

    def __init__(self, cart_pole, cart_pole_context, input_i, ouput_i, Q, R, x_star):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.DeclareAbstractInputPort("state_input", AbstractValue.Make(FramePoseVector()))
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort("control_signal", BasicVector(1),
                                     self.OutputControlSignal)
        (self.K, self.S) = BalancingLQRCtrlr(cart_pole, cart_pole_context,
                                             input_i, ouput_i, Q, R, x_star).get_LQR_matrices()
        (self.A, self.B, self.C, self.D) = BalancingLQRCtrlr(cart_pole, cart_pole_context,
                                                             input_i, ouput_i,
                                                             Q, R, x_star).get_lin_matrices()
        self.energy_shaping = EnergyShapingCtrlr(cart_pole, x_star)
        self.energy_shaping_context = self.energy_shaping.CreateDefaultContext()
        self.cart_pole_context = cart_pole_context

    def OutputControlSignal(self, context, output):
        #xbar = copy(self.cart_pole_context.get_continuous_state_vector())
        xbar = copy(context.get_continuous_state_vector())
        xbar_ = np.array([xbar[0], xbar[1], xbar[2], xbar[3]])
        xbar_[1] = wrap_to(xbar_[1], 0, 2.0*np.pi) - np.pi

        # If x'Sx <= 2, then use LQR ctrlr. Cost-to-go J_star = x^T * S * x
        threshold = np.array([2.0])
        if (xbar_.dot(self.S.dot(xbar_)) < 2.0):
            #output[:] = -self.K.dot(xbar_) # u = -Kx
            output.set_value(-self.K.dot(xbar_))
        else:
            self.energy_shaping.get_input_port(0).FixValue(self.energy_shaping_context,
                                                          self.cart_pole_context.get_continuous_state_vector())
            output_val = self.energy_shaping.get_output_port(0).Eval(self.energy_shaping_context)
            output.set_value(output_val)

        print(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two things that might help:

1. If you want to get the state of the cart-pole from `MultibodyPlant`, you *probably* want to be connecting to the `continuous_state` output port, which gives you a normal vector instead of the abstract-type `FramePoseVector`.  In that case, your call to `get_input_port().Eval(context)` should work just fine.
2. If you *do* really want to read the `FramePoseVector`, then you have to evaluate the input port slightly differently.  You can find an example of that [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/867fc0d2774d95ae067a92f0d39cb26c67dee1cf/bindings/pydrake/systems/test/custom_test.py#L678).

Comment: Thank you! I used ```get_state_output_port()``` and changed my controller accordingly and it worked! Now I got a simple energy shaping & lqr cartpole controller :)